# Using schema Auto-Detection in BigQuery and c#

Tags: c#, csv, google-bigquery

**Goal:**

Uploading a .csv file to Google BigQuery by using the [Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 -Pre](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) c# package with auto creating a table if it doesnt exists.

**Problem:**

It's [possible](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect) to auto-detect the database scheme and create a new table if it doesnt exist. This [option](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.CreateDisposition.html) is enabled by default. However, if I try to upload an .csv to a not-existing table, a new table is not created. It shows me an errormsg.

I think it might be something with the TableSchema since I don't know how to create a TableSchema based on the .csv file.

```
Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Not found: Table project-id-here:dataset-id-here.table-id-here [404]

Errors [
Message[Not found: Table project-id-here:dataset-id-here.table-id-here] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```

**Code:**

```
    string fileName = @"C:\result.csv";
    string projectId = "project-id-here";
    string datasetId = "dataset-id-here";
    string tableId = "table-id-here";

    BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
    TableSchema schema = null;

    using (FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Starting polling...");
        // This example uploads data to an existing table. If the upload will create a new table
        // or if the schema in the JSON isn't identical to the schema in the table,
        // create a schema to pass into the call instead of passing in a null value.
         BigQueryJob job = client.UploadCsv(datasetId, tableId, schema, stream, new UploadCsvOptions { SkipLeadingRows = 10 });

        // Use the job to find out when the data has finished being inserted into the table,
        // report errors etc.

        BigQueryJob result = job.PollUntilCompleted();
        // If there are any errors, display them *then* fail.
        if (result.Status.ErrorResult != null)
        {
            foreach (ErrorProto error in result.Status.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Polling ended");

    }
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality has been added in release 1.0.0-beta13. Auto-schema is needed to create the table OR you'd have to specify this by hand. The dataset has to be there, it wasnt there when I tried to upload my data.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1166